# Extracting boundary of raster into polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, polygon, convert

I have elevation data downloaded from nationalmap.gov in ArcGrid format (1/3 arc-second DEM). My main goal is to obtain the boundary / extent of each raster range that I have created by simply extracting by attributes. For example, I have a raster within the range of 3 meters and 10 meters (see attached image) and I would like this to be a shapefile and preferably a much smaller file size. It is currently 15gb uncompressed, and I cannot simply convert to shapefile as it is not given as an option when I try to use that tool. I have also tried Raster Domain via 3D analyst, but the result is still far too large and also unable to be converted to a polygon.

What would be the best approach for me to take to reach my objectives?

I have a lot of these ranges that I need to convert and then utilize in a leaflet interface.

[image]

Comment: How much detail are you willing to lose? Are you looking to extract (as an example) all pixels from 3 to 10m? A reclassify function might be an option for you then? If you don't want to do that then maybe try running the "int" tool to round up and down the pixel values. That might decrease the overall size of the raster.